# template function doesn't recognize

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```
template <class T>
class BaseStrategy
{
template<typename Period, typename Rep>
void print_time(tm t, chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction);
}
```

and the implemention is (in the same .h file)

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Rep, typename Period >
void BaseStrategy<T>::print_time(tm t, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction)
{
    /some code/
}
```

but when I compile the code I'm getting the following error:

> error: prototype for ‘void BaseStrategy::print_time(tm,
>   std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>)’ does not match any in class
>   ‘BaseStrategy’  void BaseStrategy::print_time(tm t,
>   std::chrono::duration fraction)
>         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /home/yaodav/Desktop/git_repo/test/include/BaseStrategy.h:216:10:
>   error: candidate is: template template void BaseStrategy::print_time(tm, std::chrono::duration)
>        void print_time(tm t, chrono::duration fraction);

why is this error occurred? and how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the template arguments in the definition

```
template <typename Rep, typename Period >
void BaseStrategy<T>::print_time(tm t, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction)
```

does not correspond to the order of the template parameters in the declaration

```
template<typename Period, typename Rep>
void print_time(tm t, chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction);
```

Either write

```
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
void print_time(tm t, chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction);
```

or (more confusing)

```
template<typename Period, typename Rep>
void print_time(tm t, chrono::duration<Period, Rep> fraction);
```

Comment: tnx, I didn't see that